# How to sort a Union All

Tags: t-sql

I can't get this to sort.  I want the entire result set ordered by DateId then productName and can't get it to work.

```
SELECT  d.DateId,
    s.product_name1 as productName
FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId

UNION ALL

SELECT  d.DateId,
    s.product_name2 as productName
FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId

UNION ALL

SELECT  d.DateId,
    s.product_name3 as productName
FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId
order by d.DateId, productName
```

Not sure where and how to add this order by basically.  I don't want to add an order by to each select because then I'd have subsets of orderings.  I want to order the -entire- ending result set...

Comment: The code that you have should work. The final `ORDER BY` applies to the whole result set. (Edit: Ah. just use `DateId` not `d.DateId`)

Comment: yea tried that Martin but get The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified. When I try to alter the view.  The SQL runs if I highlight it just fine but when the view tries to alter, I get that.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict are you placing this code in a view?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT  d.DateId as DateId,
        s.product_name1 as productName
    FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
    INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  d.DateId as DateId,
        s.product_name2 as productName
    FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
    INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  d.DateId as DateId,
        s.product_name3 as productName
    FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
    INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId
) AS A
order by DateId, ProductName
```

Comment: error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: this is when I try to alter the view I get this...using your technique

Answer (score 2):

refer to the column alias (in your case DateId, Productname)

```
select 1 a
union all
select 2 a
order by a desc
```

or refer to the column number

```
select 1 a
union all
select 2 a
order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Select Col1, Col2 from tblA where <some condition>
    Union All
    Select Col1,Col2 from tblB where <some condition>
    Union All
    Select Col1,Col2 from tblC where <some condition>

    Order By 1,2 -- means by first column,second column

-- or Order By Col1, Col2
```

But yours should work fine `Order by DateId,productName`

Also instead of hitting the tables Sales and SalesDate 3 times, you can improve the performance of your query by catching the common result set in some temporary table and then performing the union on the desired columns e.g.

```
SELECT d.DateId,s.product_name1,s.product_name2,s.product_name3
INTO #temp
FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId

Select t.DateId,t.product_name1 As productName From #temp t Union All
Select t.DateId,t.product_name2 From #temp t Union All
Select t.DateId,t.product_name3 From #temp t 
Order By DateId,productName

Drop Table #temp
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE for this. Or just do:

```
Select res.DateID, res.productName from 
(
SELECT  d.DateId,
    s.product_name1 as productName
FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId

UNION ALL

SELECT  d.DateId,
    s.product_name2 as productName
FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId

UNION ALL

SELECT  d.DateId,
    s.product_name3 as productName
FROM    dbo.SaleDates d
INNER JOIN dbo.Sale s ON s.saleId = d.saleId
)
order by res.DateId, res.productName
```